# List remote desktop administrative sessions in Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, remote-desktop

On our servers, we use Remote Desktop for remote administration only (the default administrative connections that are limited to two-sessions per server and don't require extra licensing).  Occasionally, we need to open Remote Desktop Services Manager to see if another session is open and possible kill it.

Under Windows Server 2012, you still have the administrative remote desktop, but the Remote Desktop Services Manager is gone.  You apparently need to configure the server for RDS deployment (which requires extra licensing and can't be done on a domain controller) in order to list which sessions are open and terminate any.  Is there any way, on Windows Server 2012 with only the administrative remote desktop, to list what sessions are open and possibly terminate them?